# Opening Explorer with HyperLink in GridView Using file://

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to open Explorer on the client side to view a directory. In my aspx webform, I have a gridview, which has a column of hyperlinks. In the aspx markup, I have the following:

```
<asp:HyperLink Text="ICPnt" id="MyDir" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "file://" + Eval("MyDir").ToString() %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

When the startup the asp.net application in debug mode with Visual Studio and move the cursor over the hyperlink, I see the popup path,

```
file://MachineName/C$/WINNT/MyDir
```

This looks correct. When I click on the hyperlink, NOTHING happens. I don't even see the cursor turning to an hourglass icon or anything. I think I am pretty close but can't see the missing step or error.

Another test:

I typed `file://MachineName/C$/WINNT/MyDir` in both Windows and Internet Explorer and got a new Explorer to pop up and display the directory content from my VM environment. As a test, I copied and pasted the same exact file:// path to my aspx markup and tested again. When I click on it, nothing happens.

```
<asp:HyperLink Text="ICPnt" id="WSM2MDir" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%# "file://MachineName/C$/WINNT/MyDir" %>' ></asp:HyperLink>
```

Any help is appreciated. THanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open an external file from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101574/how-to-open-an-external-file-from-html)

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7442489/1389973